# call method 2 after method 1 completes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For iphone, can I call method 2 after method 1 completes execution, kind of how we have for animation complete?

Comment: Do you mean asynchronously call the method 2?

Comment: yes, only after Method 1 has finished executing.

Comment: Could you give us more background about your particular case? @meronix suggested an Operation Queue, which works fine, but I'm betting that you really want something simpler like Observer or even a simple delegate pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

asynchronously, i guess... 'couse if not... 
you have just to call first method1 and then method2...

```
[self method1];
[self method2]; // will be called just when method1 has ended
```

but if you need it all working in asynchronously way you can take a look at NSOperationQueue object
It's a queue where you can add many methods, it will execute them and you can go on with your code elsewhere...
If you add 2 or more methods they will be normally executed togheter (meanwhile), but you can tell the object to execute just 1 method at a time:

```
NSOperationQueue *aQueue;
aQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
            selector:@selector(method1) object:nil];
[aQueue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];

[aQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]; //tell aQueue to execute just 1 operation at a time

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
            selector:@selector(method2) object:nil];
[aQueue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

luca